# Make Modal Bigger than Page Iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small iframe attach to the main page.
My question is if I have a modal from that iframe. How can I make it cover the main page?
Currently it only covers within that ifame.
Should I make two iframes? or one iframe will do? if so, how can I do it?

https://codesandbox.io/s/cross-origin-iframe-forked-r5mz49?file=/index.html

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-water-0be91w?file=/demo.js

Comment: If I had to guess, I do not think there's a way to do this directly. There is a workaround if the iframe is on the same domain- in your Iframe code, use `top.document` to access the parent window. Something like `top.document.body.appendChild(modal)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly. That's on purpose: many sites serve up advertisements and other elements in iframes from sites they do not control. You wouldn't want one of those advertisements to take over the page and appear like it's part of your site. That would cause serious security problems.

Unless you would want that. In which case you'd make an agreement with the people who control the advertisement site, that would allow the inner iframe to agree with the outer iframe about a specific way to communicate that a specific modal should appear. Then when the iframe gives the signal, the outer site would open the modal. It's terribly hacky, but that's how it's done when there's a legitimate reason to do it.

Comment: I'll try to modify my question with an example code. I think using postMessage will achieve this?

Comment: I edited my question and added a link